# Clear a CVPixelBufferRef using the GPU

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-video, core-media

I am writing some video processing code using `AVComposition`. Giving only the necessary background details, I receive a `CVPixelBuffer` from an apple API that I do not control. This CVPixel buffer, contains a previously rendered video frame, as they are apparently recycled by this Apple API I do not control. So my goal, is to set all the pixels in the CVPixelBufferRef to [0, 0, 0, 0] (in RGBA color space). I can do this on the CPU via this function:

```
- (void)processPixelBuffer: (CVImageBufferRef)pixelBuffer
{
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );

    int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
    unsigned char *pixel = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);

    for( int row = 0; row < bufferHeight; row++ ) {
        for( int column = 0; column < bufferWidth; column++ ) {
            pixel[0] = 0;
            pixel[1] = 0;
            pixel[2] = 0;
            pixel[3] = 0;
            pixel += 4;
        }
    }
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
}
```

Is there some way I can accomplish the same thing using the GPU? Additionally, is it possible to do this via CoreImage? as I don't know openGL and it appears quite complicated to set up.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Accelerate `vImageBufferFill`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vimage/vimage_operations/filling_buffers) to do exactly that (not GPU though). This fills BGRA with black in Swift 4:

```
let width: Int = 3
let height: Int = 3

var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
var imageBuffer: vImage_Buffer
var date: Date
let iterations: Int = 10000

let pixelBufferAttributes: [CFString: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: true, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: true]
if CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, pixelBufferAttributes as CFDictionary, &pixelBuffer) != kCVReturnSuccess || pixelBuffer == nil { fatalError("Cannot create pixel buffer.") }
if CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) != kCVReturnSuccess { fatalError("Cannot lock pixel buffer base address.") }
imageBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!), height: UInt(height), width: UInt(width), rowBytes: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!))
vImageBufferFill_ARGB8888(&imageBuffer, [0, 0, 0, 0xFF], UInt32(kvImageNoFlags))
if CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, []) != kCVReturnSuccess { fatalError("Cannot unlock pixel buffer base address.") }
```

Testing plain memset to fill small buffer with zeroes in 10000 iterations is way faster in playground. In release build with real data results will probably not differ that much.

- **accelerate:** 1629.0
- **memset:** 314.0

[image]

Comment: I have used `memset_pattern16` based on your answer, it's great, thank you! One thing to add for those who want to render a CIImage into a CVPixelBuffer: do the zeroing out before the rendering, not after rendering and being done with the pixelBuffer. My AVAssetWriter with an AVAssetWrinterInputPixelBufferAdaptor was probably using my buffers in a delayed fashion and my images were added part black to the video.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your pixel buffer is attached to [an image buffer backed by an IO surface](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1781/_index.html), you can use [`CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs//documentation/CoreVideo/Reference/CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage) to get a `CVOpenGLESTextureCache` to give you a [`CVOpenGLESTextureRef`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs//documentation/CoreVideo/Reference/CVOpenGLESTextureRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CVOpenGLESTextureRef). That will be able to vend a texture target and name so that you can bind the thing in OpenGL.

In OpenGL you can [use a framebuffer object to render to a texture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH103-SW7). Having done that you could use `glClear` to clear the thing. Call `glFinish` to create a synchronisation point with the GL pipeline and when you next check it from the CPU, your memory should be cleared.

Comment: Was able to get this going via some of apple's sample code. It was much more involved though, as I had to actually do a bunch of setup for openGL, that frankly I don't understand.

Comment: Here is perhaps a better question, will this actually offer any performance improvement over using memset to zero out the Pixel Buffer?

Comment: My instinct is that your best hope is you parallelise it — issue the glClear for buffer B, then do the CPU work on buffer A, then call `glFinish` only when the CPU wants to roll on to working on buffer B. But if you're not multithreaded already, doing the same thing by GCD would probably be equally efficient. A GPU isn't just innately going to be able to do a more efficient `memset` — you're going be bound by memory bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

I have this same problem (forcing a recycled buffer supplied by `-[AVVideoCompositionRenderContext newPixelBuffer]` to be black).

What if you use Core Image to do the heavy lifting? Something like this:

```
EAGLContext *eaglContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
CIContext *ciContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:eaglContext];

CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithColor:[CIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0]];
CVPixelBufferRef destination = [request.renderContext newPixelBuffer];
[ciContext render:image toCVPixelBuffer:destination];
[request finishWithComposedVideoFrame:destination];
CVBufferRelease(destination);
```

You would have to test the performance to know if this is any better than `memset`, but this is a better approach for my money than trying to peer into OpenGL APIs just to set a few bits.

Answer (score 2):

From [this page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2597309?start=0&tstart=0) it looks like you can directly access the `CVImageBufferRef` as an OpenGL Texture via:

```
glBindTexture( CVOpenGLTextureGetTarget( image ), CVOpenGLTextureGetName( image ) );
```

Once you have it as a texture you can use it as the draw buffer for an FBO and simply call `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` on it.

Comment: Don't seem to be having any luck with: `glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(dstPixels),CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(dstPixels));`
`glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`
`glFinish();`

Comment: You'd still need to attach it to a framebuffer before clearing it would work. But if you're using iOS instead of MacOS, then you probably want Tommy's solution below.

Comment: The more I thought about it, the more I considered that simply using memset to zero out the pixel buffer might be equally as efficient as using glClear. Any thoughts on that?